# Set a javascript object's attribute with jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

How do I correctly set a javascript object's attribute? My console.log() shouldn't return undefined.

First I declare a class:

```
function SignUpForm(myFormElement) {
  var eForm, email, password;

  this.eForm = myFormElement;
}
```

Then on page load, I instantiate the class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  myFormElement = $('form');
  myForm = new SignUpForm(myFormElement);
  console.log(myForm.eForm); // Returns undefined :(
});
```

Comment: You don't need `var eForm, email, password;` there. That isn't how you declare variables on `this`.

Comment: `var eForm` and `this.eForm` are two totally different things.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/eeC94/

Comment: The var statement is not needed, otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: The code you've posted is brain-dead simple, and cannot produce the issue you describe. There is some other error external to this code.

Comment: @Joe doesn't matter. Even if there were no form, `$('form')` *still* wouldn't be undefined, it would be a jQuery object matching 0 elements. It's impossible for the code do be doing what he says it's doing; he must have some error on his console, elsewhere in his code.

Comment: @Joe that should not matter, there will still be an object returned even if no match was made on the selector.

Comment: Not saying this will fix your issue, but you should probably declare the variables in your ready block using `var` to assure there are no scoping issues.

Comment: Removing var fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SignUpForm(myFormElement) {
  this.eForm = myFormElement;
}
```

you can safely remove your declared scope variables as they don't do anything.

Comment: You do not need `return this;`.

Comment: absolutely right.  Missed the new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe want something like this?!

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input name="email" />
    <input name="password" />
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

Here you define `SignUpForm` class and in eForm you serialize `form`:

```
function SignUpForm(myFormElement) {
    this.eForm = myFormElement.serialize();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    myFormElement = $('form');
    myForm = new SignUpForm(myFormElement);
    console.log(myForm.eForm);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eeC94/1/)

**EDIT:** If `eForm` store element, then your code is ok ... but `console.log(myForm.eForm);` doesnt make much sense, and for rest you can serialize that `form` element `console.log(myForm.eForm.serialize());`.

Comment: Why would you serialize the form?

Comment: @DonnyP - And what shoud has eForm? Its look like debug value or something

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with this currently. I don't use log much, but am not sure if you can "log" an object, or if it has to be a type string.  Other than that, the object is being set properly. myForm is an object, eForm is a property of the object with it's value being the jquery object of the selector "FORM".